# Openfire - Groups not updated on Roster from Database using custom DB

Tags: xmpp, openfire, xiff

I made this question over at the Openfire groups, but it seems to be pretty quiet out there. Maybe someone here at SO works with Xiff/Openfire and has a clue about this:

We are using an external database for users and groups, on Openfire 3.6.4 through Xiff 3.0 beta with our own client.

When a user is added on our database, the roster doesn't get updated. I am logged in as "User1". "User2" is added to the database to the same shared group, so I should see him in my roster. User2 can login and see User1 on his roster, but User1's roster hasn't been updated. Even after log out, User2 still doesn't show up on User1's roster.

Apparently the group is being cached or something. Where should I be looking at for a fix to this problem? Xiff? OpenFire? I found about the property "cache.name.maxLifetime" in the docs, but I'm not sure if this is the property I should be using to get groups to update the members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody gets here looking for an answer to this question, you can follow it here:

[Groups not updated on Roster from Database using custom DB](http://www.igniterealtime.org/community/thread/40616?tstart=0)

There's a partial solution over there at the Ignite Realtime forums.

Answer (score 0):

A better approach would be to use roster protocol (see [RFC 3921, section 7](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html#roster)) to modify the roster, perhaps by writing a component for OpenFire.  This will modify the caches in transit, as well as sending notifications to clients that are currently logged in for the user.  As well, you won't have issues with your changes getting overwritten.